# How do you call a subclass method in the baseclass method?

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance, subclass, private-members

I am sorry if this question is so confusing, I am going to try and be as simple as possible.

**TLDR;** How, in a Typescript baseclass, do you call the private method of a subclass that has to be defined in the subclass?

I have many different Typescript subclasses that require different code to do the same thing: write to a file.

90% of the base code is the same, with the specific implementation of some methods per subclass.

So I have taken the same code and put it in a base class, but that calls a method that has to be implemented on the subclass and it is preferably private.

Here is an example:

```
abstract class BaseClass {
  constructor() { }

  SetOptions() {
    // Set the options
    // Return the options
  }

  GetOptions() {
    // Get the options
    this.WriteStuff();
  }

  private WriteStuff(arg1: Item, arg2: number) {}
}

class SubClass1 extends BaseClass {
  private WriteStuff(arg1: SubClass1Item, number: number) {
    // Write stuff in the SubClass1 way
  }
}

class SubClass2 extends BaseClass {
  private WriteStuff(arg1: SubClass2Item, number: number) {
    // Write stuff the SubClass2 way
  }
}
```

SubClass1Item and SubClass2Item implement the Item interface.

All subclasses will use the same code for SetOptions and GetOptions, but WriteStuff will have individualized code in each subclass and needs to be private so it isn't called by other devs on accident.

Typescript says that I can't do this because "Types have separate declarations of a private property 'WriteStuff'". And Typescript won't let me not declare the method in the BaseClass as then I am calling a method that doesn't exist but will exist in the subclass.

Is this possible?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#abstract-classes

Comment: @zerkms Yes, I found that link and I understand the idea of abstract classes. I forgot to add that to the baseclass in the above code. I have done that now. I want to know how to use a private method, that must be defined in the subclass, in the baseclass in Typescript. Do you have any suggestions of how to do that?

Comment: The method should not be private, it should be abstract. (or protected abstract)

Comment: That is inherently incompatible with the idea of a `private` method.  It needs to be `protected` (or `public`) in order for parents/children to access it.

Comment: You might also need to make this generic in order to support the different types of `Item`.

Comment: As mentioned: if you need _any_ outside code to use it whether it's "any code" or "some code in the same package" or "some code in a superclass" by definition that code is not private. And in terms of class based OO, children know their superclass's methods, but not the other way around (nor should they). Calling a `this.functionName()` will always run the instance function, if there is one, or go up the class chain until it finds one, and then run that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Private vs. Protected

`private` methods can only be accessed in the class itself, not in any descendants.  You cannot have a `private abstract` method because this is an inherent contradiction -- if descendants need to implement it then it is not `private`.

You want to use the `protected` modifier.  Per [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#understanding-protected):

> The `protected` modifier acts much like the `private` modifier with the exception that members declared `protected` can also be accessed within deriving classes.

You want to declare in your `BaseClass` that all concretions must implement a `WriteStuff()` method. This is an `abstract` method meaning that it has no implementation in `BaseClass` and **must** be overwritten.

In your descendants, the implementation of `WriteStuff` must be `protected` rather than `private`.

### Code

```
abstract class BaseClass {
  /* .... */
  protected abstract WriteStuff(arg1: Item, arg2: number): void;
}
```

```
class SubClass1 extends BaseClass {
  protected WriteStuff(arg1: SubClass1Item, number: number) {
    // Write stuff in the SubClass1 way
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/1WGaMN)

### arg1 Type

Your classes don't all share an identical signature because they each have a different type for the first argument `arg1` passed to `WriteStuff`.  You most likely want to use a [generic class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-classes) based on the type of `arg1` or some other value.

If `SubClass1Item` and `SubClass2Item` do not extend `Item` then you absolutely *need* a generic class because the implementations of `WriteStuff` in the subclasses would not be assignable to the base.

If they *do* extend `Item` then you will not get typescript errors with the current setup.  However there is potential for runtime errors when you are calling `this.WriteStuff` from `GetOptions()` in `BaseClass`.  How does the `BaseClass` know if the `Item` that it has is assignable to the `Item` subtype that is expected in `SubClass1` or `SubClass2`?  This is where generics can help.

We make the `BaseClass` a generic based on a variable `ItemType`.  We can require that all `ItemType` variables extend a shared base `Item`, but we don't have to.

The subclasses are not themselves generic classes.  They will extend a version of `BaseClass` with the specific `ItemType` that they require.

### Code

```
abstract class BaseClass<ItemType extends Item> {
  /* ... */
  
  GetOptions(item: ItemType) {
    // Get the options
    this.WriteStuff(item, 5);
  }

  protected abstract WriteStuff(arg1: ItemType, arg2: number): void;
}
```

```
class SubClass1 extends BaseClass<SubClass1Item> {
  protected WriteStuff(arg1: SubClass1Item, number: number) {
    // Write stuff in the SubClass1 way
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/jwgn0W)

Comment: Linda! This is exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you for your clear and fleshed out answer. I really appreciate it. This did the trick. And you are right, I hadn't thought of it until now, that I will need generics. You went above and beyond answering my question. I wish I could give you more points. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript lately supports [*private field declarations*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Private_field_declarations) including [private instance methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields#Private_instance_methods). There, a possible approach would provide the sub class specific implementation to the base class' super call ...

```js
class BaseClass {

  // default implementation of private instance method.
  #writeStuff = () => void 0;

  constructor(writeStuff) {
    // at instantiation time, if appropriate, ...
    if (typeof writeStuff === 'function') {
    
      // ... overwrite the default implementation.
      this.#writeStuff = writeStuff;
    }
  }
  
  // prototypal method ...
  getOptions(...args) {
  
    // ... with access to a private instance method.
    this.#writeStuff(...args);
  }
  setOptions() {/* ... */}
}

class SubClass1 extends BaseClass {
  constructor() {

    const writeStuff = (...args) =>
      // Write stuff in the SubClass1 way
      console.log(`SubClass1 [...args] : ${ [...args] }`);

    super(writeStuff);

    // do other things
  }
}
class SubClass2 extends BaseClass {
  constructor() {

    const writeStuff = (...args) =>
      // Write stuff in the SubClass2 way
      console.log(`SubClass2 [...args] : ${ [...args] }`);

    super(writeStuff);

    // do other things
  }
}

const objA = new SubClass1;
const objB = new SubClass2;

objA.getOptions('foo', 'bar');
objB.getOptions('baz', 'biz');
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```